# problems with csv files in python language

Tags: python, csv

suppose I have a file/directory in which many .csv files are present and I have a python code that can read only one csv file and do some algorithm and store the output in an another csv file.Now I need to update that python code so that we can check the file/directory and store the output of the all csv files(which are present inside the directory) in different csv files.

```
import pandas as pd
import statistics as st
import csv

data = pd.read_csv('1mb.csv')
x_or = list(range(len(data['Main Avg Power (mW)'])))
y_or = list(data['Main Avg Power (mW)'])

time=list(data['Time (s)'])
rt=5000
i=time[rt]
k=i
tlist=[]
for i in time:
    tlist.append(y_or[rt])
    rt+=1
    if i-k>4:
        break
idp=st.mean(tlist)
sidp=st.stdev(tlist)
newlist=[]
imax=max(tlist)
imin=min(min(tlist),idp-sidp)
while imax>=y_or[rt]>=imin-1:
         newlist.append(y_or[rt])
         rt+= 1
print(rt,"Mean idle power:",st.mean(newlist),"mW")
midp=st.mean(newlist)
with open('new_1pp.csv','w',newline='') as f:
    thewriter=csv.writer(f)

    thewriter.writerow(['Idle Power(mW)'])
    thewriter.writerow([midp])
```

this is the code done by me.please update it as required in the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you can use `glob` to list all the CSV files in a directory, then read them in one at a time passing each through whatever algorithm you have, and then output them again, e.g.

```
import glob
import os

# set the name of the directory you want to list the files in
csvdir = 'my_directory'

# get a list of all CSV files, assuming they have a '.csv' suffix
csvfiles = glob.glob(os.path.join(csvdir, '*.csv'))

# loop over all the files and run your algorithm
for csvfile in csvfiles:
    # read the csvfile using your current code

    # apply your algorithm

    # output a new file (e.g. with the same name as before, but with '_new' added
    newfile = csvfile.rstrip('.csv') + '_new.csv'

    # save to 'newfile' using yor current code
```

Does that help?

*Update*:

From the comments and the updated questions, does the following code help:

```py
import pandas as pd
import statistics as st
import csv
import glob

# get list of CSV files from current directory
csvfiles = glob.glob('*.csv')

for csvfile in csvfiles:
    data = pd.read_csv(csvfile)
    x_or = list(range(len(data['Main Avg Power (mW)'])))
    y_or = list(data['Main Avg Power (mW)'])

    time=list(data['Time (s)'])
    rt=5000
    i=time[rt]
    k=i
    tlist=[]
    for i in time:
        tlist.append(y_or[rt])
    rt+=1
    if i-k>4:
        break
    idp=st.mean(tlist)
    sidp=st.stdev(tlist)
    newlist=[]
    imax=max(tlist)
    imin=min(min(tlist),idp-sidp)
    while imax>=y_or[rt]>=imin-1:
         newlist.append(y_or[rt])
         rt+= 1
    print(rt,"Mean idle power:",st.mean(newlist),"mW")
    midp=st.mean(newlist)

    # create new file name using the old one and adding '_new'
    newfile = csvfile.rstrip('.csv') + '_new.csv'    

    with open(newfile,'w',newline='') as f:
        thewriter=csv.writer(f)

        thewriter.writerow(['Idle Power(mW)'])
        thewriter.writerow([midp])
```

Comment: import pandas as pd
import statistics as st
import csv
data = pd.read_csv('1mb.csv')
x_or = list(range(len(data['Main Avg Power (mW)'])))
y_or = list(data['Main Avg Power (mW)'])
time=list(data['Time (s)'])
rt=5000
i=time[rt]
k=i
tlist=[]
for i in time:
    tlist.append(y_or[rt])
    rt+=1
    if i-k>4:
        break
idp=st.mean(tlist)
sidp=st.stdev(tlist)
newlist=[]
imax=max(tlist)
imin=min(min(tlist),idp-sidp)
while imax>=y_or[rt]>=imin-1:
         newlist.append(y_or[rt])
         rt+= 1
print(rt,"Mean idle power:",st.mean(newlist),"mW")
midp=st.mean(newlist)

Comment: with open('new_1pp.csv','w',newline='') as f:
    thewriter=csv.writer(f)

    thewriter.writerow(['Idle Power(mW)'])
    thewriter.writerow([midp])
#now by this code i am storing the out put into a new csv file.C:\data  is the path of the input csv file.I tried as u told before but failed.now can you please help me to solve it?

Comment: Are all your input and output files named in the same format, e.g., with inputs being `1mb.csv`, `2mb.csv`, etc?

Comment: actually all the input files(csv format) are in a file and the output file names are not given, I have to create a csv file file for each input file to store the data.& the formats are not same e.g. 1mb.csv, big.csv, chat.csv etc.

Comment: What the the file containing the list of input files look like? Is each file name on a new line, or are they listed with comma separated values, or is there some other format? Do the output file name have to have a specific naming convention?

Comment: the input csv file hav some values of power(mW) for different times(sec) and the all input csv files in the directory have same format only different values.the algorithm finds the mean power for a range of time(suppose 10 to 200 seconds) and store the value in another new csv file.yes the inputs are separated by comma when opened in notepad like-

Comment: I've updated the answer to put your code in my example for loop. Does that work?

Comment: the input csv file hav some values of power(mW) for different times(sec) and the all input csv files in the directory have same format only different values.the algorithm finds the mean power for a range of time(suppose 10 to 200 seconds) and store the value in another new csv file.yes the inputs are separated by comma when opened in notepad like- Time (s),Main Avg Current (A),Main Avg Power (mW)
73.3618,0.2705,1213.463
73.3620,0.2695,1208.7075
73.3622,0.2705,1213.463
73.3624,0.2705,1213.463
73.3626,0.271,1215.4351

Comment: The output should be stored in another csv file with any suitable name .Idle Power(mW)
1212.7614811280905
like this output in csv file.

Comment: C:\Users\Anirban96\PycharmProjects\project1\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/Anirban96/PycharmProjects/project1/1pp.py
  File "C:/Users/Anirban96/PycharmProjects/project1/1pp.py", line 43
    
                                     ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Process finished with exit code 1
It's showing me this output.can you please solve it?

Comment: That error looks like it's probably due to there being a bracket that is not closed. Check that all your opening brackets have a matching closing bracket.

Comment: now it's working .Thank you very much for your support and help .

Comment: No problem. Glad you got things working. If my answer helped please feel free to mark it as the accepted answer via the tick mark, or upvote it.